# Creating abstraction to validate complex objects

Tags: java

I am trying to create a validator abstraction layer. These are the points I am trying to achieve:

- My abstraction should be open for extension but closed for modification
- The clients should not have a `if...else` block to handle success or failure scenario.

## Validation statuses

```
public interface ValidationStatus {
    default void process() {

    }

    public static ValidationStatus fail(ValidationFailureCause cause, String messages) {
        ValidationFailure validationFailure = new ValidationFailure();
        validationFailure.setCause(cause);
        validationFailure.setErrorMessages(messages);
        return validationFailure;
    }

    public static ValidationStatus success() {
        return new ValidationSuccess();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ValidationFailure implements ValidationStatus {
    private ValidationFailureCause cause;
    private String errorMessages;

    public void setCause(ValidationFailureCause cause) {
        this.cause = cause;
    }

    public void setErrorMessages(String errorMessages) {
        this.errorMessages = errorMessages;
    }

    @Override
    public void process() {
        if (ValidationFailureCause.MISSING_MANDATORY_FIELDS.equals(cause)) {
            throw new MandatoryElementsMissing(errorMessages);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class ValidationSuccess implements ValidationStatus {

}
```

---

```
public enum ValidationFailureCause {
    MISSING_MANDATORY_FIELDS
}
```

## The validators

```
public interface Validator<T> {
    /**
     * Validate an object and return the validation result as a Status.
     * 
     * @param request
     *            Data to be validated
     * @return can be ValidationFailure or ValidationSuccess class instance
     */
    ValidationStatus validate(T request);

    boolean isValid(T request);
}
```

---

```
public class StringValidator implements Validator<String> {

    @Override
    public ValidationStatus validate(String request) {
        if (isValid(request)) {
            return ValidationStatus.success();
        }

        return ValidationStatus.fail(ValidationFailureCause.MISSING_MANDATORY_FIELDS, "Missing mandatory parameter");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String request) {
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(request);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator<FlightProposalRequest> {

    @Override
    public ValidationStatus validate(FlightProposalRequest request) {
        if (isValid(request)) {
            return ValidationStatus.success();
        } else {
            return ValidationStatus.fail(ValidationFailureCause.MISSING_MANDATORY_FIELDS, "Request is null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(FlightProposalRequest request) {
        if (request == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Validator<String> requestValidator = RequestValidatorFactory.getRequestValidator(String.class);

        boolean result = requestValidator.isValid(request.getArrivalAirport());
        result = result && requestValidator.isValid(request.getDepartureAirport());
        result = result && requestValidator.isValid(request.getDepartureDate());
        result = result && requestValidator.isValid(request.getReturnDate());

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is my attempt at this problem. Kindly provide your feedback on my approach. With the current setup as mentioned here, my tests are passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. So If I understand correctly, clients get an instance of `Validator` from the factory, call `validate()` and get an instance of `ValidationStatus` and then call `process()` and get an exception (or nothing). so you replaced an `if...else` block with a `try...catch` one. the client still have to check the return value to figure out what to fix. and if you ask me, it is more clear to ask
   `if (result == ValidationFailureCause.MISSING_MANDATORY_FIELDS)`
   then
   `} catch (MandatoryElementsMissing mem) {`

in addition, `Validator` interface contains a method that returns a boolean. how do you plan to prevent clients from calling it?

1. If we go along with your solution: the whole `ValidationStatus` class tree seems redundat to me.  It is just a wrappper over throwing a user defined `Exception`.  It doesn't provide extra capabilities beyond translate an enum into an `Exception` (considering that exceptions can also have String message). So I believe a design where `validate()` throws an `Exception` provides the same functionality.  If you don't want to throw the `Exception` super class, you can create a `ValidationException` super class and have all your custom exceptions extend it (much like Java's [`ReflectiveOperationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ReflectiveOperationException.html))
2. Your design determines that for a given type, there can only be one `Validator`.  This may be fine for user-defined types like `FlightProposalRequest` but it may be too restrictive for JDK types like `String`.  I imagine that you want to validate that `getDepartureDate()` is a valid date, and perhaps validate `getDepartureAirport()` against predefined list of airports (perhaps an SQL query) and so on.  You should assocaite a `Validator` with a String name (perhaps an enum).
3. lastly, regartding the validation of the attributes, I believe you can write it like this:

`return requestValidator.isValid(request.getArrivalAirport())`
`&& requestValidator.isValid(request.getDepartureAirport())`
`&& requestValidator.isValid(request.getDepartureDate())`
`&& requestValidator.isValid(request.getReturnDate());`

this has the same (if not more) level of readability as the original.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my code. `Validator interface contains a method that returns a boolean.` this is the piece of code I am not happy with but I could not think of a better alternative. If you see my design, I should be able to make nested calls to `Validator` in this ex, I made a call to `StringValidator`. Can you please help me improve this piece of code.

Comment: You are absolutely correct in the 2nd point. The `StringValidator` I currently have is too restricitve.

Comment: if you find this answer useful, please consider accepting and upvoting.

Comment: This is the best answer I have got. I am accepting it :) I will appreciate your help if you can help me with the questions I have posted as comment.

Comment: why do you have the boolean returning method? you can have only `validate()` and let the concrete classes do their processing there